# why my iOS app just goes to @synthesize, but not go to viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad further?

Tags: ios, dictionary, viewdidload

My Map app has a " Select city " button to show `worldCitiesList` when clicked using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.worldCitiesListNavigationController animated:YES];
```

But now the place for the " Select city " button has to be replaced by another button.

the " Select city " button has to be relocated to another viewcontroller created from the `MapViewController` by the following code:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.tableViewNavigationController animated:YES];
```

The `worldCitiesList` can be showed from the `tableViewNavigationController`. But we want it is still showed from the `MapViewController` as before.

So in the button of backing to the `MapViewController` from the `tableViewNavigationController`, I use following code to first back to `MapViewController`, then to show the `worldCityList`:

```
- (void) backMapView:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.worldCitiesListNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

But my app just return to `MapViewControler`, but not show the `worldCityList` further.

In my `WorldCitiesListController.m`, my iOS app just goes to `@synthesize`, but not go to `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` further.

Please help. thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Post the stack trace (if any).

Comment: Try removing your `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` call and see what happens

Comment: I think you are confusing compiled obj-c with a scripted language. The file is not read top to bottom, but compiled. Saying the app just "goes to @synthesize" makes no sense.

Comment: I think he may be talking about in the debugger when you step through it stops at @synthesize.

Comment: thanks you all for your prompt replies! the BackMapView button does nothing if I remove : [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; In other words, app still stays with TableViewController interface.

Comment: yea, inturbidus. I set breakpoints in 'WorldCitiesListController.m', it doesnot go to 'viewdidLoad' and 'viewWillappear'. I just goes to ' @synthesize cityList, delegate' . I even set NSLog within 'viewdidLoad' and ' viewWillAppear' to double-check. it really doesnot step into the above 2 places. thanks

Comment: Dear WrightsCS, the NSLog doesnot show any useful info.I 'll appreciate if any good method to recommend how to get the stack trace.thanks!

Comment: I think we need to see more code.  Have you set up a delegate?

Comment: My question solved by: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question solved by: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO'. 
thanks!